# Creating new content/node

Tags: forms, nodes, organic-groups

I want to do something very simple - create a content of a specific type when a user joins a group.

Unfortunately I can not find a simple way of how it should be done.

It can be done with rules so I've been thinking about triggering one, but the details would be awfully complicated.
I thought about having a template node that I would clone and edit, but how should I go for it? There are number of modules that do that in a strange way, while saying "it might sometimes not work properly", some people use things like `drupal_execute()`, I have found that `node_save()` has an option `$node->is_new = TRUE`.
I found someone suggesting a use of forms, but they were always very simple and were not working with complicated/custom fields. I figured that maybe something like this could work:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('my_content_node_form');
$form_state = array();
do_some_edits($form,$form_state);
drupal_form_submit($form->id, $form_state);
```

What is a proper/simple way of dealing with this issue? What I would expect see is something like `$node = node_create($content_type)` but for some reason I can not find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you have a rule that triggers when a user joins a group, and a condition that checks that the group is the group you want, then add a execute PHP action to that rule that runs this code :

```
// Build a new node object
$node = new StdClass(); 
// set the type
$node->type = 'your_content_type';
// set the language
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE; // or whatever language you use.
// this fills the node with the default data
node_object_prepare($node);
// set a custom title
$node->title = 'Nice title';
// set whatever you want, for example body
$node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'This is some text for the body';
// Set the formatting for the text
$node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['format'] = 'filtered_html';
// Save the node to the DB
node_save($node);
// If you need the node ID
$nid = $node->nid;
// Just for debugging
watchdog('your_module','Just inserted the node with nid = '.$nid);
```

The key here is that [node_object_prepare](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_object_prepare/7) sets some default values for your content type.

Comment: Thanks, I tested it and this is exactly what I need. 
node_object_prepare() does everything I was looking for. It assigns new nid, fills in the authoring information, and builds the fields of the node. I don't understand why I could not find a simple solution like this anywhere.

Comment: Glad to help, and remember http://api.drupal.org can be a great resource of information.