# How to create a node programatically with drupal_form_submit()?

Tags: 7, nodes

How to create a node by programatically submitting the existing node add form, and most importantly using it's validation process instead of re-implementing all of the property/field validation logic so we piggyback off of the existing code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating new content/node](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62953/creating-new-content-node) Also, your reason is wrong - you can use hook_form_alter() to add validators to default node form. Last but not least, it's covered by the docs and their comments on Drupal.org under[node_save](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7)

Comment: Why do think these two questions are related?

Comment: Both questions are basically "how to create node in PHP code?". And you didn't made clear why altering normal node form to add your validators is not an option.

Comment: Altering node form? What are you talking about mate?

Comment: @Mołot Definitely not a dup of the other one IMO; this is specifically asking how to create a node by programatically submitting the existing node add form, and most importantly using it's _validation process_. It's fairly common practice to do this, for example in service resource callbacks. In such cases there's no point re-implementing all of the property/field validation logic so we piggyback off of the existing code.

Comment: @FranciscoLuz The mention of `node_save()` is a bit confusing, I would remove that entirely. The fact that you need to use the default node validation is enough to warrant the question in its own right. The form submission process calls `node_save()` internally so to say you can't use it might be a bit misleading. Also there aren't any more or less hooks fired by using the form submit method, those are all fired from `node_save()`

Comment: @Clive Cheers mate. I have edited the question and removed the reference to node_save.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The advantage of this method over [node_save](https://drupal.org/project/field_validation) is that if you have field validation done by modules like [field_validation](https://drupal.org/project/field_validation) or your own custom validations that you have previously implemented, the node saving will fail if the data sent does not comply with those validations.

```
global $user;
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');

$node = (object) array(
  'uid' => $user->uid,
  'name' => $user->name,
  'type' => 'MYCONTENTTYPE',
  'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
);
node_object_prepare($node);

// Get default values from attached fields.
$fields = field_info_instances('node');
$form_state = array();
foreach($fields['MYCONTENTTYPE'] as $field_name => $values) {
  $form_state['values'][$field_name] = array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array());
}

// Add the $form_state field values.
$form_state['values']['title'] = 'my title';
$form_state['values']['body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = array(
  'value' => 'my body',
  'format' => 'full_html',
);
$form_state['values']['field_MYFIELD'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'blah blah';

// Without this line, not quite sure why, it wont work.
$form_state['values']['op'] = t('Save');

drupal_form_submit('MYCONTENTTYPE_node_form', $form_state, $node);

// Tell watch dog if any of the fields fail validation.
$errors = form_get_errors();
if (!empty($errors)) {
  foreach ($errors as $field_name => $message) {
    watchdog('MYMODULE', '%field: %message', array('%message'=> $message, '%field' => $field_name));
  }
}
```

Comment: What if you already have the node object with proper field values ready to be inserted? Do you still have to manually enter the field values in the $form_state['value'] array?

Comment: @Mike No, you don't. I've put it up there only to illustrate how it must be structured, the drupal_form_submit() won't discriminate on how the $form_state['value'] array was put together or where it came from as soon as it is structure like that.

Comment: So how do you do it? I have a user object and I want to create the $form_state['values'] array automatically

Comment: @Mike I don't see the relation between the user object and the $form_state array, could you elaborate a bit more.

Comment: IN you example you use write $form_state['values']['title'] = 'title';

Comment: sorry.. Did not finish the previous comment.
In you example you write $form_state['values']['title'] = 'title'; For my use case, I have a loaded $node (or $user) object so I would do something like: $form_state['values']['title'] = $node->title; I need to do this manually for the body field AND every other field. 
I was wondering if there is a way to automatically construct the $form_state['values'] array since I already have the data loaded in the object.

Comment: @Mike In core I believe there is no routine for doing that but you can create your own quite easily. It is a matter of you creating a function which receives the $node object and returns the $form_state array. You have to keep in mind that my example is just a structural logic and hardly can be used the way it is.

Comment: Do not use 'und', use instead of that the LANGUAGE_NONE definition!