# programmatically saving a node doesn't add any record to dblog

Tags: 7, nodes, log-messages

When I call `node_save` to save a node, no record for "a new node has been saved.." is added to watchdog.

Is this normal? If yes, how do I also add a watchdog record? (without calling the `watchdog` function directly)

Comment: you generally get a message..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that the save operation is not logged during [`node_save`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7) is because it is done during the node form submission process by [`node_form_submit`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form_submit/7) which internally uses node_save.

Please refer [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77046/how-to-create-a-node-programatically-with-drupal-form-submit) elaborate and well-written response of saving the node using `drupal_form_submit` answered by user [Francisco Luz](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2328/francisco-luz). Pasting the code for the sake of completion here for saving an article resulting in both the watchdog logging and the `drupal_set_message` of the acknowledgement.

```
global $user;
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');

$node = (object) array(
  'uid' => $user->uid,
  'name' => $user->name,
  'type' => 'article',
  'language' => 'und',
);
node_object_prepare($node);

// Get default values from attached fields.
$fields = field_info_instances('node');
$form_state = array();
foreach($fields['article'] as $field_name => $values) {
  $form_state['values'][$field_name] = array('und' => array());
}

// Add the $form_state field values.
$form_state['values']['title'] = 'my title';
$form_state['values']['body']['und'][0] = array(
  'value' => 'my body',
  'format' => 'full_html',
);
//$form_state['values']['field_MYFIELD']['und'][0]['value'] = 'blah blah';

// Without this line, not quite sure why, it wont work.
$form_state['values']['op'] = t('Save');

drupal_form_submit('article_node_form', $form_state, $node);

// Tell watchdog if any of the fields fail validation.
$errors = form_get_errors();
if (!empty($errors)) {
  foreach ($errors as $field_name => $message) {
    watchdog('MYMODULE', '%field: %message', 
      array('%message'=> $message, '%field' => $field_name));
  }
}
```

I did run this once with devel php console and it logged the node during the node creation. Hope this helps.